# Unable to boot into my OS X after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows, macos, mac, hard-drive, boot-camp

Ok I am in major trouble here!

I wanted to install Windows 8 in my Mac.. So I used BootCamp to partion my HardDisk and allocated some 100 GB for Windows..   All was well and Windows was installed..

After logging into windows, I further portioned the C: drive, using Right Click Computer --> Manage --> Disk Management... I shrunk my C: drive from 100 GB to 60 GB and named the new partion as D: which now has 40GB.. I messed around with the system-assigned partitions(the Mac partition, a 200 MB partition and 1 other) changing the drive letters a few times

Now when I restarted the system and went to boot menu(by pressing Option button), I could only see my Windows partition.. No way to log into my OS X!

What do I do? Was my tinkering around with the system partition drive letters somehow responsible for this? If no, then what is the problem?
And how do I rectify this and log into my OS X??

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: I hope you backed up your Mac OS X partition first.

Comment: @PaulR  Do you know how to restore my backup from my Windows 8??

Comment: I suggest booting from your Mac OS X install DVD and then use Disk Utility to try and repair the partition first.

Comment: OK. seems my iMac did not come with a Mac OS X DVD..  Aaargh! 
Any ideas @PaulR?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you deleted the OS-X partition when creating the Windows partition, considering there was not one in the "Boot Menu".

Comment: Nope.. There was no way of "deleting" the OS-X partition when partitioning using Boot Camp Assistant! It only allowed me to specify the size of the Windows partition.

Comment: I think he meant from the windows disk management screen, since you said you messed around with the 200mb partition (probably the UEFI boot partition)

Comment: @Justin  Oh.. that would be the logical conclusion then, but by "messing around" I only changed the drive letters of the partitions(apart from shrinking the original partition). Sounds insane, but does just changing the drive letter have such terrible consequences?

Comment: No, drive letter changes will be local to that install of windows, unless you change the drive from basic disk to dynamic disk (to allow windows raid 0/1/etc) as this also writes the disk letters to the partition. (this would also break any non-windows OS on there though).