# How to restore Mac from Windows 8

Tags: windows, macos, mac, backup, partitioning

Recently I ran into a problem (as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/527824/unable-to-boot-into-my-os-x-after-installing-windows-8)) where I couldn't log into my OS X.

I have Windows 8 installed in a partition, but unfortunately the partition where OS X was installed has been erased somehow(the partition shows as dynamic, so I assumed it was erased/formatted.. If someone knows better please correct me)..

TO CUT TO THE CHASE, I have an entire backup of my Mac.. Is it possible to restore the backup in the partition where OS X was previously installed THROUGH WINDOWS 8 BECAUSE I CANT LOG IN TO OS-X??

Hope I made sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to a point that it is bootable. You have two basic options, depending on what you are trying to do.

### Recover the files

I use software called HFSExplorer to let me mount .DMG images and HFS+ Formatted partitions/drives. I can copy data *from* Mac OS formatted drives to my Windows installation. Works on Windows 8, even though it is not advertised. The program is also free.

### Get OSX up and running

This will require the Setup DVD (or USB), as it recovers *everything* saved in the Boot Camp image. Boot from the DVD or USB, select your language, then from the Tools menu, choose "Restore from Time Machine", and follow the instructions. Because you are booting from the OSX Disc or USB, you will not be booting into Windows. Also, note that this will clear off your hard drives that originally had OSX installed on it

Comment: the second method then..  Guess I'd have to start searching for that darn OS X CD :(  
Just 1 question : if "this will clear off your hard drives that originally had OSX installed ", will the Windows partion be safe?

Comment: The Windows part should be safe as long as you don't tell DiskUtil to do anything to it, and don't adjust the partitions.

Comment: @SatheeshJM From personal experience, it has wiped out my Windows (Bootcamp) partition along with the rest of the drive. If Everett has a way of doing it without wiping out Windows, I'd be interested to know how

Comment: I don't mind my Windows partition being wiped out.. just asked to know what would happen.. Anyway Thanks for the replies guys! Will post updates after reinstalling & restoring everything.